# Romanian business visa Member state of first entry

Tags: visas, applications, business-travel, romania

I'm planning to attend a conference in Romania. My route would be
Melbourne -> Abu Dhabi -> Amsterdam -> Bucharest
In Romanian visa application (no Schengen), I need to fill

1. Member state of first entry
2. Border post of entry into Romania
3. Member state of main destination (this is mandatory)

Can someone tell me what should I put for these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised they ask about information about other member states as they are not part of the Schengen Area yet, but based on the information you provided, I suppose it would be:

1. The Netherlands
2. Bucharest airport
3. Romania

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I also wonder what they have to do with this information since it is only Romanian visa, not the Schengen.

Comment: Upvoted, will mark as the answer once I receive visa hopefully :)

Comment: As I udnerstand it, Romania's entry to Schengen is imminent, and possibly, existing Romanian visas will be valid throughout Schengen when that entry takes place.